# NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdecimalnumber

NSDecimalNumber is saved with lesser number of zeros, I enter in textfield $6000,00 for example, but in tableview appear $6,00

Please help me solve this issue

Below is my code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter;
@synthesize currencyFormatter;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    nameTextField.text = editGift.nameOfGift;

    currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    priceTextField.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[editGift priceOfGift]];

}

- (IBAction)saveChanges:(id)sender {
    editGift.nameOfGift = nameTextField.text;

    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSDecimalNumber *priceAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:priceTextField.text];
    editGift.priceOfGift = priceAmount;

    AppDelegate *myApp = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [myApp saveContext];
    [self.delegate editGiftViewControllerDidSave:self];
}
```

Display in tableView:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init]; 
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle]; 
cell.giftCostLabel.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[gift priceOfGift]];
```

Comment: Add code - currency formatter and how you display the value.

Comment: Please can you check my code I added currency formatter and how i display value in my tableview. Thank you

Comment: You already formatted the Number to Currency format So no need to convert that again in table view. Did you got a chance to Try my code ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but there are warnings: editGift.priceOfGift = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:priceAmount]; Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSDecimalNumber *' from 'NSString *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code may be helpfull for you.

```
 - (IBAction)saveChanges:(id)sender {
        editGift.nameOfGift = nameTextField.text;


    NSDecimalNumber *priceAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:priceTextField.text];

     editGift.priceOfGift =priceAmount;



        AppDelegate *myApp = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        [myApp saveContext];
        [self.delegate editGiftViewControllerDidSave:self];
    }
```

in Tableview try This

```
 NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];


cell.giftCostLabel.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:editGift.priceOfGift];
```

Comment: editGift.priceOfGift = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:priceAmount];  Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSDecimalNumber *' from 'NSString *'

Comment: Check my Updated Code (Just Removed Currency formatter while saving the data)

Comment: I tried your code, thank you but In the simulator tableview shows NaN,  on the device appear the number 60 instead of 6000. Very strange :(

Comment: Please can you watch video explanation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGFEmZrIECc

Comment: You have to Check Whether the number is already in Currency Format or not (As per the Video ,When you enter normal number its working and if you enter number in Currency format its returning NAN ). So if The number is Already in Currency format then no need to format it again.